# How to make a custom class be removed when calling Array#compact

Tags: arrays, ruby

If using have a custom nil class (null object pattern) is it possible to have it removed from an array when calling `.compact` on the array. (Something like overriding `.nil?` to return true)

e.g. A game board where the empty squares contain `NilPieces` and have `board.flatten.compact` return only the non-nil pieces.

Comment: Sadly, `compact` uses explicit check instead of calling `nil?`. You can monkey patch `Array#compact` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `compact` is hardcoded to filter out by `NIL_P`, which tests whether the datatype is `Qnil` (in C code, so there's nothing you can do about it).

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [`Array#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) rather than compact:

```
arr = [nil, 5, 'Hello']
arr.reject do |el|
  el.nil? || el.is_a? String
end
#⇒ [5]
```

Or, assuming your `NilPiece` responds with `true` to `nil?`, the above might be shortened to (credits to @Stefan):

```
arr.reject &:nil?
```

Please note, that there is an inplace version: `reject!`.

Comment: I think the question was how to implement a class to behave as a `nil` object rather than how to filter some objects from an array.

Comment: @ndn I think the question was about “is it possible to have it removed from an array,” but maybe you’re right; let’s wait for what OP thinks.

Comment: @mudasobwa to customize your answer to OP a bit: `arr.reject{ |el| el.is_a? NilPiece }`

Comment: Assuming the OP's custom nil class responds to `nil?` with `true`, you can write `arr.reject(&:nil?)`

Comment: I am aware you can do it with `reject` I was specifically wondering if I could get the same functionality using `compact`.